# シーケンス対象となっているリストは、popで取り出しても、内容が不変だから、その原因がどうしてなのかということと、順に取り出す方法を知りたい。

Tags: python, python3

```
import itertools
value_text = [['an applean orange', 'an orangean apple'], ['a pena ball', 'a balla pen']]
value_text =  itertools.product(*value_text)
solid_text = ['I have ', '.You have ', '.']
copy_text = solid_text[:]
text_seq = []
new_seq = []
for k,text in enumerate(value_text):
    length = len(solid_text) + len(text)
    pri_text = list(text[:])
    for j in range(length):
        if j%2 == 1:

            a = list(pri_text).pop(0)
            print("pri_textの値:",list(pri_text))
            print(a,"が入りました。")
            text_seq.append(a)                      
        else:
            b = solid_text.pop(0)
            print("solid_textの値",solid_text)
            print(b,"が入りました。")
            text_seq.append(b)
    new_seq.append(text_seq)
    solid_text = copy_text[:]
    text_seq = []

print("結果",new_seq)
```

**このコードを実行することによる狙い。**
偶数ごとに`solid_text`、奇数ごとに`value_text`を順次取り出しては新しいリスト入れ込んでいき、一つのシーケンスへと合体させていく処理を実装したいです。

例えば、最初のシーケンス実行後は、
`['I have ','an applean orange','.You have ','a pena ball','.']`
という状況を作りたいです。
そのためには、`if j%2 == 1:`以下にある、`(pri_text).pop(0)`で、少なくともこの`pri_text`の内容が、順次取り出されて少なくなっていってくれる必要があります。
ところが、`pop`メソッドの利点である、漸減処理ができません。
したがって、`pri_text`の内容は、どんなに実行しても、元の内容のままであります。
おかげで、結果はこうなります。
**結果**

`[['I have ', 'an applean orange', '.You have ', 'an applean orange', '.'], ['I have ', 'an applean orange', '.You have ', 'an applean orange', '.'], ['I have ', 'an orangean apple', '.You have ', 'an orangean apple', '.'], ['I have ', 'an orangean apple', '.You have ', 'an orangean apple', '.']]`

---

強制的に実現するに当たり、コードを以下のようにしました。
結果は、望む形となりました。

**強制的実現のためのコード**:

```
import itertools
value_text = [['an applean orange', 'an orangean apple'], ['a pena ball', 'a balla pen']]
value_text =  itertools.product(*value_text)
solid_text = ['I have ', '.You have ', '.']
copy_text = solid_text[:]
text_seq = []
new_seq = []
for k,text in enumerate(value_text):
    length = len(solid_text) + len(text)
    pri_text = list(text[:])
    for j in range(length):
        if j == 1:

            a = list(pri_text).pop(0)
            print("pri_textの値:",list(pri_text))
            print(a,"が入りました。")
            text_seq.append(a)    
        elif j == 3:       
            a = list(pri_text).pop(1)
            print("pri_textの値:",list(pri_text))
            print(a,"が入りました。")
            text_seq.append(a)    
        else:
            b = solid_text.pop(0)
            print("solid_textの値",solid_text)
            print(b,"が入りました。")
            text_seq.append(b)
    new_seq.append(text_seq)
    solid_text = copy_text[:]
    text_seq = []

print("結果",new_seq)
```

**結果(望む形)**：

```
[['I have ', 'an applean orange', '.You have ', 'a pena ball', '.'], ['I have ', 'an applean orange', '.You have ', 'a balla pen', '.'], ['I have ', 'an orangean apple', '.You have ', 'a pena ball', '.'], ['I have ', 'an orangean apple', '.You have ', 'a balla pen', '.']]
```

---

**質問**

望む形になるために、`pop`が漸減的処理を行ってほしいのですが、そうならない理由はなぜでしょうか？
　コードを実行していただくとわかりますが、`solid_text`と、`pri_text`は、このように変化します。

```
solid_text:
 solid_textの値 ['.You have ', '.']
 solid_textの値 ['.']
 solid_textの値 []
 pri_text:
 pri_textの値: ['an applean orange', 'a balla pen']
 pri_textの値: ['an orangean apple', 'a balla pen']
```

以下ずっとこれ。

このため、`pop(0)`から順に取り出そうとしても、全く`pri_text`の内容が減ってくれないため、常に'an orangean apple'側が選ばれてしまいます。(なぜあえて`pri_text`に一度要素をコピーしているかというと、値だけを得れば後はただのリスト同様、変化してくれるとおもったからです。)

`solid_text`の方は、しっかり`pop`の効果が働いているのに対して、なぜ`value_text`イテレータ型から取られた、`text`変数は、(別の変数に値をうつしたとしても、)`pop`の影響を受けないのでしょうか？

そして、これを解決するいい方法はありませんか？現在ごり押しで結果を得ようとしていますし、そこまでのスキルの持ち主でもないため、エレガントな方法を探しています。なお、
`value_text`と、`solid_text`は、サンプルコードでは固定長ですが、実際は、可変長ですので、よろしくおねがいします。
**（追記）**
mjyさんのご指摘により、pri_textをたlistで2回くくってしまったがために、popによる処理が反映されていないということでした。
　そこで、これは自己回答として残し、新しい疑問は再度質問として載せようとおもいます。

Comment: `pri_text` を直接扱わず、`list(pri_text)` のように `list` に渡しているのはなぜですか？

Comment: @mjy 一度タプル処理で怒られたからその名残です。popはリストじゃないと使えないよという警告を受けたためだったと記憶しています。確かに要らない処理ですね。

Comment: なるほど。
ならば現在 `pri_text` はタプルでは無いのですから、`list` は不要ですね。
`list` で新規リストを生成するのを止めれば、とりあえず `pop` で変更されないという問題は無くなるはずです。

Comment: @mjy　本当だ。望む形になりました。ありがとうございます。でも逆にいちいちlistに入れ込めば、popの影響を受けないのはなぜなのだろうと思うようになりました。これは質問としておかしいというところはありませんか？

Comment: Haruさんが抱えている、「`pop` で変更されない」という問題は、例えば `l = [1, 2, 3]; list(l).pop(0); print(l)` で再現できます。
このように、[「最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)を参考に質問に記載するするコードを最小限のものにすると、回答が得られやすいと思います。

Comment: 一応疑問としては成立しているようなので、調べてみてそういう疑問がどこかになかったらまた出してみたいと思います。

Comment: 原因はともかく、`[list(itertools.chain(map(next, itertools.cycle(v)), *v)) for v in [[iter(solid_text), iter(u)] for u in value_text]]` などはいかがでしょう。

Comment: @metropolis すごすぎですね。いただきます。もし解答にしていただけたらチェックします。

Comment: まぁ、何と言いますか python だからこそできる事ではありますね。解答については Haru さんの回答に追記してもらってかまいませんよ。

Comment: @metropolis 正直pythonすごいと言われてどうすごいのかよくわかりませんでしたが、かなりよくわかりました。どうお答えすればいいかわかりませんので、おっしゃられるようにしておくことにします。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a = pri_text.pop(0)`
にすると、望む形が得られます。

`list`で、listを括ってpopの処理を行っても、リストの要素が減ることはないようです。
また、これを行った後だと、望む結果が得られるので、どちらも解決ということになります。

metropolis さんより　いただきました。

for 文以下のコードはこれで表現できます。

```
new_seq =　[list(itertools.chain(map(next, itertools.cycle(v)), *v)) for v in [[iter(solid_text), iter(u)] for u in value_text]]
```